# popup layout in android?

Tags: android

I was trying to make my UI as neat as possible, 
The user should enter some values into a circuit diagram,so I was trying to make the user click the resistor for example, then, a pop-up window appear with an EditText field in it for the user to enter the value of the resistor.

So far I was able to do that by using two separate setContentView()s, one for the circuit diagram and the other holds the EditText field, but I want the layout with the circuit Diagram to be visible in the background while the pop-up is the one in focus.

something like this (random example from the web):
http://blog.itechtalk.com/wp-content/2010/10/SMS-Popup-1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).  See [creating dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually smsmpopup uses an activity with theme dialog in it's manifest. Check the src code.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. u want something as a Dialog... but if its an activity.. u can set this paramenter in the androidmanifest file..

```
    android:name=".Pick_Color"

    android:label="Pick a Color !"

    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

this will make the screen as neat and Dialogish as possible